# No entiendo como imprimir un arreglo bidimensional en c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks, c++17

En mi clase de programación 1, hemos estado viendo arreglos, funciones y manejo de archivos. Por lo que mi maestro nos ha dejado que hagamos un programa donde se le muestra al usuario 4 opciones, 1. Agregar estudiante, 2. Visualizar la lista de estudiantes, 3. Ordenar y 4. Salir. Los ejemplos que nos han enseñado hasta el momento han sido de cómo imprimir en un archivo de texto un arreglo unidimensional, sin embargo en este caso debemos imprimir un arreglo bidimensional(nombres de los estudiantes y sus notas respectivas). A continuación les muestro mi código.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>
#define F 5
#define C 10
#include "Libreria.h"
int main () {
    FILE *f;
    int opc;
    int cont = 0;
    char Nom[F][C];
    char Estudiantes[100][50];
    float Not[F][3];
    float Notas [100][50];

    ///Haciendo lectura inicial
    f = fopen("Estudiantes.txt", "r");
    if (f==NULL){
    cout << "El archivo no existe pero se creara\n";
    f = fopen("Estudiantes.txt", "w+");
    }
    else{
    //Leyendo contenido del archivo y almacenandolo en la matriz de contactos
    while (feof(f)==0){
    fgets(Nom,50,f);
    fgets(Not,50,f);
    strcpy(Estudiantes[cont], Nom);
    strcpy(Notas[cont], Not);
    cont++;
    }
    fclose(f);
    }
    do{
        system("cls");
        opc = menu();
        switch(opc){
            case 1:
                captura(Nom, Not, cont);
                cont++;
                break;
            case 2:
                mostrar(Nom, Not, cont);
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Ha elegido la opcion de ordenar los elementos del arreglo. \n";
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "Ha elegido abandonar el programa. \n";
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Error, no ha ingresado una opcion valida. \n";
                break;
        }
        system("pause");
    }while (opc!=4);

    return 0;
}
```

y esta es la libreria que utilizo para mi tarea:

```
 #ifndef LIBRERIA_H_INCLUDED
 #define LIBRERIA_H_INCLUDED
 #include <string.h>
 int menu(){
    int op;
    cout << "Menu de opciones. \n";
    cout << "1. Agregar estudiantes \n";
    cout << "2. Mostrar lista de estudiantes \n";
    cout << "3. Ordenar \n";
    cout << "4. Salir \n";
    cout << "Digite una opcion \n";
    cin >> op;
    return op;
  }

  void captura (char Nom[F][C], float Notas[F][3], int cont){
    char n[C];
    float n1, n2, n3;
    cout << "Digite el nombre del estudiante: \n";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Ingrese la nota 1: \n";
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "Ingrese la nota 2: \n";
    cin >> n2;
    cout << "Ingrese la nota 3; \n";
    cin >> n3;
    strcpy(Nom[cont], n);
    Notas[cont][0] =n1;
    Notas[cont][1] =n2;
    Notas[cont][2] =n3;
  }

  void mostrar (char Nom[F][C], float Notas[F][3], int cont){
    if (cont==0){
        cout << "La lista esta vacia. \n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Nombre\tN1\tN2\tN3\n";
        for (int i=0;i<cont;i++){
            cout << Nom[i] << "\t";
            cout << Notas[i][0] <<"\t";
            cout << Notas[i][1] <<"\t";
            cout << Notas[i][2] <<"\t";
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
  }


#endif // LIBRERIA_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: No termino de entender tu duda ... en la última función que has puesto se hace justamente eso, se imprimen los resultados de dos arrays: `Nom` y `Notas`

Comment: Intento crear un archivo de texto con los dos arrays

Comment: Sustituye `cout` por un objeto de tipo `ofstream` que apunte al fichero destino ... pero vamos, una cosa es imprimir y otra es almacenar en un archivo.